R package Remotes import update of dependency package
I have an R package (bayer) which imports another package I wrote and is installable through github (riptw). To add it in bayer imports I needed to add in DESCRIPTION:
# ... rest of DESCRIPTION

Remotes:
    cccnrc/riptw

When I make an update in riptw, is it checked and re-installed when bayer is re-installed from users? If not, how can I ensure this?
